# Dynamic Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007

All,

In the past I created a lot of dynamic Excel (2003) spreadsheets in the following ways:

1.Using Excel COM object,
2.XML representation of spreadsheets,
3.SyncFusion controls for creating Excel Spreadsheets

All the above generated from C#.NET Code

Now my question is what are the best tehcnologies for creating Excel 2007 spreadsheets?
Has anything changed ? I know Excel 2007 is much more advanced than 2003.
Please note my needs have changed now and I need to create even more complex spreadsheets that include pivots etc.

Again I want to create these new spreadsheets using .NET Framework.

Thanks,
Marios

Answer (score 0):

Because 2007 Office files are XML packages, they are created as Packages with FW 3.0.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931866.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question on StackOverflow:

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/114029)

I think ExcelPackage can be a fit when it comes to Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the SpreadsheetGear library - it is commercial but a lot faster than the COM approach.

Another benefit: no dependencies on the client machine, you could use e.g. OpenOffice as viewer

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/